# Are there any good performance profiling tools for websites? (frontend)

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome, profiling

I am wondering if there are some good **free** performance profiling tools for websites, and specifically the frontend. This is mainly about Javascript.

The problem with existing tools like for example Google Pagespeed, is that it doesn't work for my application. Before you can get into my application you need to login, but since Google Pagespeed doesn't do this, it only scans the login page.

I know some of you will refer to the Google Chrome Dev tools, but I was hoping on something a little 'easier'. Well, not easy, but I am having trouble finding the functions that use the most RAM or are blocking the UI from rendering etc.

You have to understand, I am not against Chrome's Dev tools. So if someone has some clear tutorials, that you think is worth mentioning, please don't hesitate.

If possible, I would like to avoid uploading the source code somewhere.

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YSlow plugin seems to work without refreshing the page.
I am able to login to a secured app and run the tests:
- YSlow http://yslow.org/

I'm not sure If this helps or if you are looking for an automated product.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!